# What is the most efficient way to get all subtrees from node array and edge vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

Assume that there are nodes as array and undirected edges as vector like this:

```
int nodes[n] = {1, 2, 3, ... ,n };
vector<pair<int, int>> edges;

edges.push_back(std::make_pair(0, 2));
edges.push_back(std::make_pair(2, 4));
```

where each element of array is value and `n`is the number of array. Following above code, there are two edges. One is from 0 to 2. The other one is from 2 to 4. These numbers indicate index of array. In this case, size of largest sub-tree is 3 that 0-2-4 and size of smallest sub-tree is 1 obviously.

I solved this like below:

1. Sort `edges` vector
2. Choose one permutation in `edges`
3. Repeat 2 until exploring all possible cases

However I am not sure this is efficient way. 
How can I get all sub-trees in the problem domain like this? is there any general and efficient way?

Comment: I misunderstood the question and have deleted my answer. For generating all pairs your algorithm seems fine. Just think about how to make the choosing part more efficient. You can use hash maps to keep track of which nodes are in current subtree to add edges more effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using BFS (Breadth First Search) based on edge information. To avoid making cyclic graph and keep nodes as tree, I use `set`. And I also apply `sort` before searching. It is useful to reduce time complexity.

```
void BFS(set<int> nodes, vector<pair<int,int>>& edges, vector<set<int>>& result) {
    result.push_back(nodes);
    int lastNode = *max_element(nodes.begin(), nodes.end());
    auto findIt = find_if(edges.begin(), edges.end(), [](const pair<int, int>& element){ return element.first == lastNode});
    if(findIt != edges.end()) {
        nodes.insert((*findIt).second);
        BFS(nodes, edges, result);
    }
}

sort(edges.begin(), edges.end());

vector<set<int>> result;
for(auto it : edges) {
    set<int> nodes;
    nodes.insert((*it).first);
    nodes.insert((*it).second);
    BFS(nodes, edges, result);
}
```